# Error while upgrading postgres

Tags: upgrade, postgresql

Ubuntu 14.04. Package manager reported that postgresql was broken. When I tried to upgrade it produced the following error:

```
(synaptic:30668): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_child_watch_add_full: assertion 'pid > 0' failed
(Reading database ... 377899 files and directories currently installed.)
 Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-9.3_9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb ...
 * Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                       *            Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in -d at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 354.
 Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in concatenation (.) or string at   /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 355.
 Error:  is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                     [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
* Stopping PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                                       * Use  of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in -d at /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 354.
Use of uninitialized value $info{"pgdata"} in concatenation (.) or string at  /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster line 355.
Error:  is not accessible or does not exist
                                                                     [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript postgresql, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.3_9.3.5- 0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/postgresql-9.3_9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1_amd64.deb
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
 A package failed to install.  Trying to recover:
 Setting up postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 (2.1.2+dfsg-2) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of postgresql-contrib-9.3:
 postgresql-contrib-9.3 depends on postgresql-9.3 (= 9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1); however:
 Version of postgresql-9.3 on system is 9.3.4-1.

 dpkg: error processing package postgresql-contrib-9.3 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured 
 Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-contrib-9.3
```

PGDATA variable is assigned in /etc/profile.d and is present in all shells.

Comment: Try again, you might have caught the postgresql packages in mid change.

Comment: Tried, same error.

Comment: You're running postgresql 9.3.4-1 and should update to 9.3.5-0, so where did the 9.3_9.3.5-0 package(s) come from?

Comment: It probably got downloaded when Package Manager upgraded postgresql-contrib-9.3. When I run 'sudo apt-get upgrade' I get      `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-contrib-9.3 : Depends: postgresql-9.3 (= 9.3.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.1) but 9.3.4-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
`

Comment: Did you try the suggestion, sudo apt-get -f install ?

Comment: Yes, it produces same error as in OP.

Comment: Edit the /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster script and after line 354, add the two values which might trigger the error.  Then you will know better what the problem is, might be permissions.

Comment: I put two lines before the error line: `print 'info_pgdata = ' . $info{'pgdata'} . "\n";
    print 'info_owneruid = ' . $info{'owneruid'} . "\n";` They both produced empty strings.

Comment: I'm not sure what it did but when I changed first line in pg_ctlcluster to include -d (debug) flag in went through, although it did report some errors in the process.